# Simple Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ find $P(S_3+S_1=S_4+S_6)$

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

> Given state space $\mathbb{Z}$ and a markov chain $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $P(X_k=1)=1/2$ and $P(X_K=-1)=1/2$

> Find $P(S_3+S_1=S_4+S_6)$

I have a formula to compute $P(S_n=k)$ so I believe I want to simplify to that form.

My attempt:

$P(S_3+S_1=S_4+S_6)=P(\sum_{k=1}^3 X_k+\sum_{k=1}^1 X_k=\sum_{k=1}^4 X_k+\sum_{k=1}^6 X_k)$

Rearranging the sums I get $P(X_1-X_4-\sum_{k=1}^6X_k=0)$

I think by symmetry I can say that $-\sum_{k=1}^6 X_k=\sum_{k=1}^6 -X_k=S_6$

So I could rearrange again to $P(S_6=X_4-X_1)$ I know that they are either $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability so do I have to compute the sum $P(S_6=2)+P(S_6=-2)+P(S_6=0)$ for the possible value of $X_4-X_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for $P(-2X_4=X_2+X_3+X_5+X_6 )$ so you have independent variables on each side with easy distributions

You can easily find the distributions of each side:

```
Value      -2X_4   X_2+X_3+X_5+X_6
  -4          0        1/16
  -2         1/2       4/16
   0          0        6/16 
  +2         1/2       4/16
  +4          0        1/16
```

which makes the probability of equality $0+\frac12 \frac4{16}+0+\frac12 \frac4{16}+0=\frac14$